# pythonic return in try

Tags: python, return, try-catch

What is the correct way to deal with return of function in try block?

Option 1:

```
def someFnc1() -> bool:
    try:
        fetchSomeData()
        return True
    except:
        return False
```

Option 2:

```
def someFnc2() -> bool:
    try:
        fetchSomeData()
    except:
        return False
    return True
```

Comment: I don't think this is related to Python. In my opinion, the try block should only contain code that may raise exceptions. I would prefer the second option.

Comment: Neither one is "pythonic". Bare `except:` clauses like that are almost never a good idea as they trap every possible `exception` (system and user) so can hide bugs and make it more difficult to find and fix them. They especially bad when they're silently ignored as your code looks like it may effectively be doing.

Answer (score 1):

This is described [in part in PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/):

> Additionally, for all try/except clauses, limit the try clause to the absolute minimum amount of code necessary. Again, this avoids masking bugs.
>
> Yes:

```
try:
    value = collection[key]
except KeyError:
    return key_not_found(key)
else:
    return handle_value(value)
```

> No:

```
try:
    # Too broad!
    return handle_value(collection[key])
except KeyError:
    # Will also catch KeyError raised by handle_value()
    return key_not_found(key)
```

Based on this your second version should be considered most pythonic (i.e. the absolute minimum of code inside the try clause).